# Configuration Serialization Format

Tags: c#, serialization

I am asking for some common Serialization formats to store store the settings for a particular application. I am looking for a format that is easy to handle and optionally there is a class to handle that in .NET [External or Internal(like XML)]. I am aware of the Ini format but some .NET Devs recommend XML. So asking for a fairly simple to handle Configuration storage file format.
Hope, I make sense.

Thanks, 
WritZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML is easily human-read, and .NET has great built-in support for reading settings from XML files. It even abstracts the serialization and you just read/write settings from/to at the program. I'd also recommend XML for this reason. You may also try JSON or Binary serialization, but only if you have some specific reasons for *not* using XML.